# Data not getting bound/updated to templates?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular app that reads data out of a local CSV file. However, sometimes (maybe 10-20% of the time) the data doesn't seem to be getting bound, so my pages are missing all the `{{data}}` interpolations. But then if I refresh the page (sometimes it takes multiple refreshes), the data will eventually appear.

I can't figure out what the problem is. Since the app is just reading data out of a local CSV file, it shouldn't have trouble getting the data, and the process should be deterministic anyways.

Also, if I log the data to the console, the console does display the data appropriately. The page just isn't displaying it for some reason. (e.g., `{{company.name}}` on my page is blank, but if I call `console.log(company.name)` in my code right after I set the `$scope.company = ....` variable, I do see the company name being displayed in my console).

Any ideas what the problem might be? Is the problem that Angular doesn't know the variable is being set/updated for some reason?

EDIT: this is what my controller and HTML look like more or less.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngSanitize"]);

app.controller("CompaniesController", ["$scope", "$http", "$routeParams", "$window", "FlashService", "$location", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $window, FlashService, $location) {
  $scope.data = [];
    
  $scope.index = parseInt($routeParams.i === undefined ? 0 : $routeParams.i);
  
  d3.csv("data/data.csv", function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.company = $scope.data[$scope.index];
  });
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  
  <title>Foo</title>
  <script src="assets/js/d3.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/underscore.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>      
  <script src="assets/js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="routes.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  
<div ng-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
<h1>{{company.name}}</h1>
```

Comment: First of all check console for errors

Comment: Yup, I checked the JS console -- there are no errors.

Comment: I think i know. Problem is digest will not run after csv loading. You should run it manualy using $asyncApply or $timeout Check this idea pls

Answer (score -1):

Angular refresh the view only if you use `$http` to make XHRs.

Here you call the outside world through `d3.csv`. So you need to tell Angular to run the digestion when the data is available.

```
  d3.csv("data/data.csv", function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.company = $scope.data[$scope.index];
    $scope.$apply(); // here
  });
```

Comment: Using  $scope.$apply(); is a very bad idea. You can get $digest already in progress in a random time. Do not do this and do not advise to others